# ORA-04091 table * is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper, mutating-table

I am working on a project that rents boats to customers and based on information they enter supplies them with a boat. One section of this project I want to create a trigger that based on when you leave with the boat vs when you return it will calculate the days and then either refund money to the customer balance or charge extra. I have my trigger setup like so -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BALANCE_FEE
AFTER INSERT ON CHARTERS
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
FEE NUMBER;
ACL_DATE DATE;
EXP_DATE DATE;
GRP_ID NUMBER;

BEGIN

SELECT ACL_RETURN_DATE, EXP_RETURN_DATE, GRP_ID INTO ACL_DATE, EXP_DATE, GRP_ID FROM CHARTERS;


IF ACL_DATE > EXP_DATE
THEN
FEE := (ACL_DATE - EXP_DATE) * 75;

IF ACL_DATE < EXP_DATE
THEN
FEE := (ACL_DATE - EXP_DATE)* -20;

ELSE
FEE := 0;
END IF;
END IF;
UPDATE CUSTOMER
     SET CUSTOMER.BALANCE = CUSTOMER.BALANCE + FEE
     WHERE CUSTOMER.GRP_ID = GRP_ID;
END;
/
SHOW ERROR;
```

If it also helps here is the two tables that I have that relate to this trigger.

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
    CUS_FNAME VARCHAR(20),
    CUS_LNAME VARCHAR(20),
    GENDER VARCHAR(20),
    PHONENUM NUMBER(10),
    CITY VARCHAR(20),
    PARTY_COUNT INT,
    GRP_ID VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    BALANCE NUMBER);

CREATE TABLE CHARTERS (
    CHARTER_ID VARCHAR(20),
    BOAT_ID VARCHAR(20) REFERENCES BOAT(BOAT_ID),
    GRP_ID VARCHAR(20) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(GRP_ID),
    EXP_RETURN_DATE DATE,
    ACL_RETURN_DATE DATE);
```

When I run the code I get this error report

```
INSERT INTO CHARTERS (CHARTER_ID,BOAT_ID,EXP_RETURN_DATE,ACL_RETURN_DATE,GRP_ID) VALUES ('T003','B003',DATE '2019-05-5',DATE '2019-05-07','G003')
Error report -
ORA-04091: table ADMIN_BF.CHARTERS is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "ADMIN_BF.BALANCE_FEE", line 9
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'ADMIN_BF.BALANCE_FEE'
```

What exactly is the problem here? Is it something to do with my trigger being an "After Insert"?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't select from a table which is being updated right now, as it is "mutating". Instead of the `SELECT` statement, do this:

```
acl_date := :new.acl_return_date;
exp_date := :new.exp_return_date;
grp_id   := :new.grp_id;
```

The rest of code should be OK afterwards.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I have ran into another error now probably dealing with date subtraction. Maybe you can help me figure out this problem too. INSERT INTO CHARTERS (CHARTER_ID,BOAT_ID,EXP_RETURN_DATE,ACL_RETURN_DATE,GRP_ID) VALUES ('T003','B003',DATE '2019-05-5',DATE '2019-05-07','G003')
Error report -
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at "ADMIN_BF.BALANCE_FEE", line 11
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'ADMIN_BF.BALANCE_FEE'

Comment: DATE literal must be in YYYY-MM-DD format; the first you posted is not (should be 05, not 5). When subtracting two DATE values, the result is NUMBER of days between them, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I just fixed that issue but I am still getting it.
INSERT INTO CHARTERS (CHARTER_ID,BOAT_ID,EXP_RETURN_DATE,ACL_RETURN_DATE,GRP_ID) VALUES ('T003','B003',DATE '2019-05-05',DATE '2019-05-07','G003')
Error report -
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at "ADMIN_BF.BALANCE_FEE", line 11
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'ADMIN_BF.BALANCE_FEE'

Comment: Which line is line #11?

Comment: Line 11 is the line right before 
ACL_DATE := :NEW.ACL_RETURN_DATE;

Comment: I opened a new question pertaining to this specific problem and will mark this question solved. Thank you for your help @Littlefoot

Answer (score 0):

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_Facturation1_UID
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON Facturation1
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
v_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
IF INSERTING THEN
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count
FROM Facturation
WHERE FacturationId = :NEW.FacturationId;
IF v_count = 0 THEN
INSERT INTO Facturation(FacturationId, TransportId, DateFacture, MontantFacture, MontantRglt, DateRglt, ModeRglt,  UserDateTDWH, UserNameDWH)
VALUES(:NEW.FacturationId, :NEW.TransportId, :NEW.DateFacture, :NEW.MontantFacture, :NEW.MontantRglt, :NEW.DateRglt, :NEW.ModeRglt, TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'),USER);
END IF;
END IF;

```
IF UPDATING THEN
    INSERT INTO Facturation(FacturationId, TransportId, DateFacture, MontantFacture, MontantRglt, DateRglt, ModeRglt,  UserDateTDWH, UserNameDWH)
    VALUES(:NEW.FacturationId, :NEW.TransportId, :NEW.DateFacture, :NEW.MontantFacture, :NEW.MontantRglt, :NEW.DateRglt, :NEW.ModeRglt, TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'),USER);
END IF;

IF DELETING THEN
    INSERT INTO Facturation(FacturationId, TransportId, DateFacture, MontantFacture, MontantRglt, DateRglt, ModeRglt,  UserDateTDWH, UserNameDWH)
    VALUES(:OLD.FacturationId, :OLD.TransportId, :OLD.DateFacture, :OLD.MontantFacture, :OLD.MontantRglt, :OLD.DateRglt, :OLD.ModeRglt, TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'), USER);
END IF;
```

END;
/

Comment: ORA-04091: table WKSP_DRONES.FACTURATION is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "WKSP_DRONES.FACTURATION_TRIGGER", line 16
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'WKSP_DRONES.FACTURATION_TRIGGER'
ORA-06512: at "WKSP_DRONES.TRG_FACTURATION1_UID", line 9
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'WKSP_DRONES.TRG_FACTURATION1_UID'

Comment: The SQL answer you provided looks like a good one. If you do the following, you'll greatly enhance readability:
1) Instead of copy pasting in some SQL, set the context with a sentence or two about what you're going to show them.
2) move the SQL that you already provided into a "code block" so its easy to read and people will readily want to use it.

Thank you for sharing your intellect on StackOverflow!